# Graph Isomorphism : Extract only TRUE from the Boolean value

Tags: r, igraph

Here is the code for finding graph isomorphism between every graph object. and it will work fine.

```
g1 <- graph.ring(10 , directed = FALSE)
g2 <- graph.ring(5 , directed = FALSE)
g3 <- graph.ring(7 , directed = FALSE)
g4 <- graph.ring(10 , directed = FALSE)
g5 <- graph.ring(5 , directed = FALSE)

g <- list(g1,g2,g3,g4,g5)
g 


iso = function(g,i,j)
{ 

   r <- graph.isomorphic(g[[i]],g[[j]])
   return(r)
   print(g[[i]])
   print(g[[j]])

} 
loop_results <- list()
for(i in 1:5)
{
  for(j in 1:5)
  {
    loop_results[i][j] <- list(NULL)
    r= iso(g , i , j)
    print(r)
    print(g[[i]])
    print(g[[j]])
    loop_results[[i]][[j]] <- list(r=r)
 }

}
m <- loop_results
m
```

m gives the result in the form of list which is return Boolean value TRUE or FALSE because the function graph.isomorphic return TRUE if the graphs are isomorphic otherwise it returned FALSE.

Now i want to fetch only TRUE value from m. I will run the following code but it will not give me the answer which i want. It return an error: Error in print(m[i][j] == TRUE) : (list) object cannot be coerced to type 'logical'. 
Can any one help.

```
for(i in 1:5)
{
  for(j in 1:5)
  {
    print(m[i][j] == TRUE)

  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have a "rectangular" set of conditions to test, it would be a lot easier to collect them in a matrix:

```
loop_results <- matrix(NA, 5,5);for(i in 1:5)
{
  for(j in 1:5)
  {    
    r= iso(g , i , j)
    loop_results[i,j] <- r
 }
}
m <- loop_results
m
#-----------
      [,1]  [,2]  [,3]  [,4]  [,5]
[1,]  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE
[2,] FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE
[3,] FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE
[4,]  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE
[5,] FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE
```

That result is susceptible to using the `which` function with its `arr.ind` parameter>

```
> which(m, arr.ind=TRUE)
      row col
 [1,]   1   1
 [2,]   4   1
 [3,]   2   2
 [4,]   5   2
 [5,]   3   3
 [6,]   1   4
 [7,]   4   4
 [8,]   2   5
 [9,]   5   5
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your response. If i have a large number of graph object like 30 or more than 30 then i will get 30*30 matrix and from that matrix i have to manually check where TRUE is.

Comment: so is there any way that i can only fetch the true value and not other.     Thank you.

Comment: Thanks for that, but i doesn't mean that. i just want all the value which gives TRUE not any other.

Comment: The only "values" in your result are TRUE and FALSE. Your result doesn't deliver any "values which give TRUE". My result at least tells you which of the inputs "give TRUE". Try this for each of the rows in my (second) result: ` iso(g ,1,1 ) #[1] TRUE`